# How to automatically update a constantly-changing Excel source link in Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have pasted a link (via Paste Special) from an Excel spreadsheet to a Word document.

However, there is a new Excel spreadsheet created monthly to be linked to this Word doc - which means the source link in Word will need to be updated every month. The naming convention for these spreadsheets are  "yyyy-mm" and they are always created in the same folder/location.

I know how to manually change the source link once a month, but how could I go about automating this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use indirect() to build the name with the latest date.